# svn import doesn't doesn't work properly

Tags: svn

I have created a new branch and did `svn import` of the source files and folders from the old branch. When I check-out my files and folders , I got everything, however strangely I notice some of the files are still link to old URL. I found this by doing `svn info`. Because of this the file shows `S conflict`. Folders in which this file contains belongs to new URL. How do move specific file to new URL? Why i didnot change the URL when in first place when I did svn import?

Also I have seen some files starting with "!" exclamation. I donot have those files in my directory. I'm unable to check-in files because this. How do I remove them from commit list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a strange situation. What you normally do when you create a branch are the following steps:

1. Decide which part of your file system (often the whole trunk) will be branched.
2. Go to that location in your repo browser (if doing that visually) or enter the corresponding command in your shell. Something like: `svn copy <old URL> <new URL> -m "<Commit message>"` (see the chapter ["Creating a branch"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create) for details). Everything surrounded by `<>` has to be filled out by you. The essential part is the **`svn copy`**.
3. As a result, a cheap copy will be done inside your Subversion repository.
4. Then you checkout your branch somewhere else locally or switch your current checkout location to the branch.

Using `svn import` will fill the repository with new items, and these should not be part of a working copy anyway.